# OAuth2.0 implementation and validation by Resource server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement/validate OAuth2.0 in my .net framework 4.5 version of Web API.
i bound SSO service to my App and
also have client Id, client Secret, service url, token url and so on.

My API is resource server and after the client hits on our endpoint url how can we validate?
i tried by adding OWIN middlewear but didn't get any idea to proceed.

Also this is .net framework version, plus didn't find any reasonable solution.